# IntelliJ IDEA does not group Python imports

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

As mentioned in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports,

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. Standard library imports.
> 2. Related third party imports.
> 3. Local application/library specific imports.
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

It works when I choose the system Python 3.6 interpreter as the project SDK but when I select a virtualenv, the standard library imports and third-party ones are mixed together.

Without finding any related settings in the IDE, I tried resetting the IDE configurations and re-creating the whole `~/.virtualenv` directory from scratch. Neither of them helped.

And actually the same setup works just fine in macOS (Python 3.7) and I just cannot be more confused... Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I have to remove `/usr/lib64/python3.6` from Project Structure -> SDKs -> Classpath, although `/usr/lib64` is actually a symbolic link to `/usr/lib` in my system.

Guess I'd submit an issue to them...